# Can the QBO API indicate the account is using the US or international version?

Tags: quickbooks-online

Our system is dealing with QBO users from the states and other countries. Does the API support to indicate the account is using US or international edition? It is essential as the tax model is very different on the 2 versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you query for CompanyInfo with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CompanyInfo;
```

You'll get back a response with a `Country` field like this:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-07-11T08:30:10.953-07:00">
   <QueryResponse maxResults="1">
      <CompanyInfo domain="QBO" sparse="false">
         <Id>1</Id>
         <SyncToken>3</SyncToken>
         <MetaData>
            <CreateTime>2013-04-20T10:32:18-07:00</CreateTime>
            <LastUpdatedTime>2013-07-11T08:27:06-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
         </MetaData>
         <CompanyName>n57GbCorp.</CompanyName>
         <LegalName>n57GbLegal Corp.</LegalName>
         ...
         <Country>US</Country>
         ...
```

Reference these docs:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/companyinfo

Comment: I'm not sure. Apparently one may use the international edition with a US address.

Comment: There are separate address fields for the business location, etc.   That `Country` tag is a stand-alone tag indicating the country flavor of QBO itself.